# How do I isolate the value?

Tags: r

I am running the most simple code I can imagine. All I'm doing is asking R to import a csv file, choose a column, and then show me the value.

```
DEXUSUK = read.csv('C:/Users/Seth Reuter/Google Drive/GSU/Financial Engineering/Final Project/DEXUSUK.csv')
ExchangeRates = DEXUSUK$DEXUSUK
```

All I need to do is pull `ExchangeRates[1]`, which should return a single value. Instead I'm getting.

```
> ExchangeRates[1]
[1] 1.4451
2018 Levels: . 1.3658 1.3728 1.3757 1.3780 1.3811 1.3840 1.3960 1.3972 1.3974 1.3989 1.4018 1.4023 1.4034 ... 2.1104
>
```

What is that `2018 Levels` stuff? And how do I get rid of it?

This is what I've tried.

```
> ExchangeRates[1]$Value
Error in ExchangeRates[1]$Value : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> ExchangeRates[1]$VALUE
Error in ExchangeRates[1]$VALUE : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> ExchangeRates[1]$value
Error in ExchangeRates[1]$value : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

The file I'm using is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Vy-139qib8b1VyQUZLM2ZQQlE/view?usp=sharing). I downloaded it from the federal reserve economic database.

Comment: You got a single value.  It is 1.4451.  The remaining part is alerting you that `ExchangeRates` is a factor not a number. There is probably something in the file that is not a number.

Comment: And that something is likely related to the isolated `.` that R thinks is one of the levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the `DEXUSUK` column contains "." characters to indicate missing values. So `read.csv` interprets that column as strings, not numbers. And because you did not specify `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, the strings are then converted to factors.

There are many solutions to this issue. One is to import data using the RStudio wizard, which provides you with fine control over how to process the columns. The fix using `read.csv` is this:

```
DEXUSUK <- read.csv("C:/Users/Seth Reuter/Google Drive/GSU/Financial Engineering/Final Project/DEXUSUK.csv", 
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
                    na.strings = ".")
```